# Replacing FIOS rental router

Tags: networking, router

I have a bundle TV+Internet FiOS Service from Verizon.

```
FIOS cable (basement) ->  ONT (basement) ->  FiOS Quantum Gateway Router (other side of the house)
```

I want to accomplish a few things:

1. Save on the rental fee
2. Have more parental control & firmware updates
3. Better firewall so I can build a home cloud server
4. Run two RJ45 Ethernet cables to my TV and my PC for top speed on those devices.

My OTN is in the basement.  I want to put my router there, as well.  Then add an AP for better coverage.

Just don't want to lose the guide and VOD.

Thinking of Netgear X4S (R7800) or Asus Wireless AC3100 Gigabit Router.

Any gotchas in my plan?

Comment: If you supply your own modem, you surrender assistance for internet outages at the hands of your ISP.  I would be inclined to keep their modem Ask them if you can purchase it (may not be possible). Put it in Bridge Mode. Then supply your own router for household controls including parental controls and usage times.

Comment: You are aware that in most cases, even if you own the modem, you can't typically perform the firmware updates yourself?  Even if you can, you wouldn't want to do the updates yourself, your ISP has send your modem their specific configuration once they provisioned it to your account.  What I typically do is I purchase the modem (to save on the fee) and get myself a router.  I connect all devices to the router and disabled any wireless capability on the modem.  I am in full control over my router, let the ISP worry about the configuration of the modem, all is good at that point.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind, is that with your own router and router setup as we have suggested, the ISP can swap out the modem if need be without upsetting your setup. This has happened to me as the ISP has upgraded their network